# Helplessly vs. Haplessly

Tags: word-usage

> Due to lack of knowledge, they roam haplessly in search of jobs.
>
> Due to lack of knowledge, they roam helplessly in search of jobs.

Which of these two words seems to be the better fit?

Comment: Personally, I'd put a comma after the word "knowledge" in both.  Of course, I like commas.  Otherwise, this is a usage question, not a grammar question.

Comment: corrected @Exal

Comment: Wouldn't you usually say "in search *of* something"?

Comment: Corrected @GrahamNicol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hapless* is used in a *limitative* way as defined in [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hapless).

> having no luck : very unfortunate

Exmaples:

> She plays the *hapless* heroine who is unlucky in love. 
>    The *hapless* motorist had barely paid his bill and driven away from the body shop> when a truck sideswiped his car

[helpless](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/helpless) means:

> lacking protection or support

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/helpless):

> Unable to defend oneself or to act without help.

Lack of knowledge might make them *hepless people*, but, I don't think it is appropriate to use the adverb form of "haplessly" in the context.

You get only 91 hits when googling "walk haplessly" and 993 hits for "walk helplessly". It shows *walk haplessly* is rarely used.

It is not a matter of grammar. I believe it is a matter of which word better fits into the context.

Note: "In search *of*" is used far more often than "in search *for*"

Comment: Missed earlier but corrected now

Comment: @AnandKumar Good. Glad that I could help.

Comment: Very well explained too

Answer (score 3):

I am concerned that neither *haplessness*, nor *helplessness*, are directly informed by a 'lack of knowledge'. I suppose a lack of knowledge could be the reason for an inability to find help, and could also predicate bad luck (*haplessness*). But strictly *luck*, or a lack of it, is something that occurs independently of one's personal preparedness.

I have an idea that the adverb you need is ***aimlessly***.

Also the preposition should be ***of***, not *for*. Grammatically it is either *they roam...in search of jobs* or *they roam...in a search for jobs*. If using *for* an indefinite article is required.

Comment: Aimlessly sounds rather vagoue

Answer (score 2):

They're both grammatically correct.  *Hapless* means luckless; *helpless* means unable to act effectively on one's own.

Unless you think that having knowledge increases the holder's luck, the context would make *helpless* seem the more appropriate to the sense of the statement.

Comment: Whilst I have upvoted you here, I am concerned that neither haplessness, nor helplessness, are directly informed by a 'lack of knowledge'. I suppose a lack of knowledge could relate to an inability to find help. But I have an idea that the adverb the OP needs is *aimlessly*.

Comment: @WS2 I take your point, and grant an comment uptick for *whilst*.  I'm not sure about *aimless*.  One could wander ineffectively (through bad luck or lack of knowledge) but still have the aim of getting a job.  If the lack of knowledge extended to knowing how to apply for a job, I  think one would be literally helpless, i.e., would require assistance, to get a job, but that goes an interpretative distance beyond the OP.